# Calculation of energy expectation value for a well similar to hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian

For a function $$\psi(r)=\frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}}$$

and $\hat{H}=\frac{-\hat{p}^2}{2\mu}-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0\hat{r}} $ : $\mu$ being mass , we have to calculate the energy expectation value.

I have proceeded as follows:

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \hat{H} \left(\frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \right)$$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \left( \frac{-\hat{p}^2}{2\mu}-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0\hat{r}} \right) \left(\frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \right)$$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \left( \frac{-\hat{p}^2}{2\mu}-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0\hat{r}} \right) \left(e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \right)$$

with $\hat{p}^2=-\hbar^2 \Delta^2 = -\hbar^2 \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial{r}^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \right)$ (I have only written laplacian in spherical co-ordinates in terms of r and not $\theta$ and $\phi$ because the function $\psi(r)$ is only dependent on r).

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \left( \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} {\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial{r}^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial{r}} \right)}-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} \right) \left(e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \right)$$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \left( \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} {\left( \frac{\partial^2 e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} }{\partial{r}^2}+\frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} }{\partial{r}} \right)}-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} \left(e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \right) \right) $$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \left( \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} {\left(\frac{r^2}{a_0^4}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2a_0^2}}-\frac{e^{-\frac{r^2}{2a_0^2}}}{a_0^2} -\frac{2}{r} e^{-\frac{r^2}{2a_0^2}}\frac{r}{a_0^2}\right)}-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} \left(e^{\frac{-r^2}{2a_0^2}} \right) \right) $$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{a_0^3}} \left( \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} {\left(\frac{r^2}{a_0^4}e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}}-\frac{1}{a_0^2}e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} -\frac{2}{a_0^2}e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} \right)}-\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} \left(e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} \right) \right) $$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\frac{1}{a_0^3}}\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}   \frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} {\frac{r^2}{a_0^4}e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{1}{a_0^2}e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{2}{a_0^2}e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} }-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} \right] $$

Solving the integration(if it converges) would further give:

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{a_0^3}\left[\frac{\hbar^2}{8\mu a_0^4} {a_0^3\sqrt{\pi}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu a_0^2}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}a_0}{2} -\frac{\hbar^2}{a_0^2\mu} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}a_0}{2}}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} \right] $$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{a_0^3}\left[\frac{\hbar^2}{8\mu a_0} {\sqrt{\pi}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu a_0}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} -\frac{\hbar^2}{a_0\mu} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} \right] $$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{a_0^3}\left[\frac{\hbar^2}{\mu a_0} {\sqrt{\pi} \left( \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2}\right)} -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} \right] $$

$$\langle \hat{H} \rangle= \frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{1}{a_0^3}\left[\frac{\hbar^2}{\mu a_0} {\sqrt{\pi} \frac{-5}{8}} -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}} \right] $$

I could only manage this far and I couldn't converge the last integral : $-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}}  $

The correct answer is however : $\frac{-3\hbar^2}{4\mu a_0^2} -\frac {e^2}{2a_0 \epsilon_0 \sqrt{\pi}}$

I really don't understand how it is obtained ?

Comment: Where's the integration variable? Did you remember that in spherical coordinates you need to integrate over $4\pi r^2\,\mathrm{d}r$?

Comment: Please don't use $*$ to indicate multiplication. This is not a site about app code. Just use *legato*: $AB$ instead of the wretched $A*B$.

Comment: For $-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^2}{4\epsilon_0r} e^{\frac{-r^2}{a_0^2}}$, try Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+0+to+infinity+%28e%5E-%28x%2Fa%29%5E2++dx%29

Comment: @wihtedeka why do we use $4\pi r^2 dr$ ..is it because of volume integral ?

Comment: @Gert I have tried wolfram it doesn't converge ..but perhaps with $4\pi r^2 dr$ it will..I will have to check it.

Comment: Not sure what you're problem is: WA calculates $\int_0^{+\infty} u^2 e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u$ w/o problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to look through every single step, but from what I can tell you missed the fact that the expectation value is really meant as a volume integral.
\begin{align*}
\langle H \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}^3r\ \psi^*(\mathbf{r}) H(\mathbf{r)} \psi(\mathbf{r})
\end{align*}
If you want to change from cartesian to spherical coordinates you need to include the determinant of the jacobian in your volume element. For spherical coordinates this comes out to be
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{d}^3 r = \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z = r^2 \sin(\theta) \mathrm{d}r\, \mathrm{d}\theta\, \mathrm{d}\varphi
\end{align*}
Since your wavefunction (and thus the action of the Hamiltonian) doesn't depend on the angles you can do the integral over the angles
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\varphi \int_0^\pi \mathrm{d}\theta\ \sin\theta = 4\pi 
\end{align*}
which means you have to include a factor of $4\pi r^2$ in your integrals.